# Is there a binary operation over the nonnegative reals satisfying the metric and group axioms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, metric-spaces, real-numbers

Is there a binary operation over the nonnegative reals which satisfies the [metric axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)) and the [group axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics))? I.e., find an $f : S \times S \to S$ such that $(f,S)$ follows the group and metric axioms ($S$ is a set of nonnegative reals) or prove that there is no such function.

I have tried $f: (a,b) \mapsto |a - b|$, but it is not associative. Some of other that I have tried are

1. $f: (a,b) \mapsto |a + b|$
2. $f: (a,b) \mapsto |a.b|$
3. $f: (a,b) \mapsto |a / b|$

**EDIT** : I am trying XOR operation and to me it appears a valid choice.

Comment: Let $e$ be the group identity. Then $f(e,e)=e$. But by one of the metric axioms, $f(e,e)=0$. So you must have $e=0$, and $f(e,x)=f(x,e)=x$. This rules out a few things you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered in [this MathOverflow thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16214/is-there-an-associative-metric-on-the-non-negative-reals). Yes, there is such an operation, but the proof is highly nonconstructive.

Comment: Thanks for answer. what about XOR operation ?

Comment: @shiva If you mean XOR on the binary expansion (e.g., $0.11011\dots\ast 0.01100\dots = 0.10111\dots$) then you run into problems with recurring ones. For example, $0.01111\dots$ and $0.10000\dots$ are the same real number.